# Power Calculations for 3 arm clustered randomised trial

Tags: r, sample-size

I need to do power calculations for a 3 arm trial (to determine minimum detectable effect size, given the alpha, power, sample size etc). I found the R package Three.Arm.Trials, however I was wondering how to account for ICC in clustered randomised designs using this. I want to identify the minimum detectable effect size of treatment vs reference and placebo vs reference, and check whether my sample size is sufficient to detect a significant difference between the two (i.e. treatment vs reference being significantly greater than placebo vs reference). Would be very grateful for any insight, or even suggestions for other softwares I could use! Thank you.

Comment: Hi Smriti This question is probably more suited to the SO stats sister site Cross Validated. https://stats.stackexchange.com.  However they will probably want a bit more practical detail too.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks a lot for your response. Will try it out on cross validated with more detail!